# Fastboot recovery: Partition recovery not support flash

Tags: android, root, partition, fastboot

I am trying to install cwm recovery through fastboot. I tried executing the command

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

But I am getting the error as partition 'recovery' not support flash. Please any one help me to fix this. Whether I need to change anything on the recovery partition?

Comment: Have you installed the HBOOT drivers and the Android SDK?

Comment: Yes, its going into fastboot mode. adb and fastboot are working fine in command prompt. Also "adb devices" and "fastboot devices" are showing my device.

Comment: Worth checking the basics first I guess. That's strange, the next thing I guess is what device do you have, do yo have the correct CWM version for that device? Usually when I see this happen it is due to the device being a fake, or the wrong file being flashed, or a PIT file used in error. Could something like this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1982576 help you at all?

Comment: SP Flash tool is very new to me. Can you explain how to proceed? And CWM version might be right one. My device is Lenovo S920, running official 4.4.2, which I received as update OTA 2 days before.

Comment: I don't use SP Flash myself, nor do I ever use CWM (I've had nothing but issues over the years) so I can't say to be honest. Did you try something like : http://www.jellydroid.com/2013/11/how-to-install-cwm-on-lenovo-s920/ this maybe? It might help out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

try this:
first, root your device, and install root explorer. go to **/system/** and delete this file "**recovery-from-boot.p**".
use SP Flash tool, and install cwm through it.
it's worked for me (lenovo a316i)

Comment: Unable to find "recovery-from-boot.p" file in root explorer